# Adding product and attribute using PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

This is data comes from API

```
[diamond] => Array
        (
            [diamond_id] => 90466377
            [shape] => Round
            [size] => 0.33
            [color] => G
            [fancy_color_dominant_color] => 
            [fancy_color_secondary_color] => 
            [fancy_color_overtone] => 
            [fancy_color_intensity] => 
            [clarity] => SI2
            [cut] => Excellent
            [symmetry] => Excellent
            [polish] => Excellent
            [depth_percent] => 61
            [table_percent] => 56
            [meas_length] => 4.47
            [meas_width] => 4.5
            [meas_depth] => 2.74
            [girdle_min] => 
            [girdle_max] => 
            [girdle_condition] => 
            [culet_size] => None
            [culet_condition] => 
            [fluor_color] => 
            [fluor_intensity] => Faint
            [has_cert_file] => true
            [country] => Hong Kong
            [city] => Hong Kong
            [lab] => GIA
            [total_purchase_price] => 433.62
            [total_sales_price] => 850
            [currency_code] => AUD
            [currency_symbol] => AUD$
            [total_sales_price_in_currency] => 1080.5523
            [cert_num] => 7276144251
            [stock_num] => RG611
            [has_sarineloupe] => false
            [sarineloupe_url] => 
            [is_fancyColor] => false
        )
```

I want to add this as a product I have added product success fully but I'm not able to add attribute (Clarity, Cut, Symmetry, Polish).
I want to apply these attribute on the product. After adding these attributes should show in attribute section of woocommerce product

Comment: Have you tried anything, like adding a new product programmatically or with csv data and the woo importer? or the API

Comment: yes i tried adding grammatically also added product without attributes. I need to add this using code i cant use any plugin here.

Comment: You can use custom fields or product attributes then

Comment: How? can you give me some example.by the way I want to add these as a woocommerce attribute using code custome field is plugin right?

Comment: custom fields are not part of a plugin. you can use the add_post_meta and many examples can be found by searching. You can start by reading here https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: I'm new to wordpress thanks sir i will try this now